# "Convincer" em português europeu

Tags: tradução-inglês, português-europeu

Estava a ler um texto em inglês e surgiu o seguinte termo

> The Great Convincer

Quando tentei traduzir mentalmente para português europeu, tive alguma dificuldade na palavra "convincer", que designa alguém que convence.

Então, eu sei que em português brasil existe a palavra [convencedor](https://www.dicio.com.br/convencedor/). No entanto, a palavra convencedor não existe na norma europeia, na grafia pré-Acordo Ortográfico. Existe, no entanto, as palavras persuasor ou instigador, mas *parece* que carregam um bocado de conotação negativa, pelo que tenho as minhas dúvidas se neste caso são as mais indicadas.

Comment: convincer is not in good dictionaries. It is a bad buzzword. Ou seja não está dicionarizado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando uma frase ao ser traduzida (O Grande Convencedor). não soa idiomática em outra língua, ou não agrada ao tradutor, existem diversas formas de se dizer exatamente, ou quase exatamente, a mesma coisa:

1. Ele(a) convence muito bem.
2. Ele(a) sabe convencer.
3. Convencer é com ele(a) mesmo.
4. **Um(a) artista/perito/expert na arte de convencer.**
5. Como ele(a) convence bem!
6. Aquele(a) que sabe convencer.

São apenas sugestões, e uma tradutora profissional certamente terá sugestões até mais adequadas. Em negrito a minha preferência.

Comment: Obrigado Centaurus!

Comment: The word does not exist in English. So....

Comment: @Lambie   "convincer" (noun) can be found in Merriam-Webster, The Free Dictionary, Wikitionary, and a few other less reliable sources.  I wouldn't be so categorical as to state the word does not exist.

Comment: It is most certainly is not in Merriam-Webster, which you can check like I did.

Comment: @Lambie     You missed it.                Other Words from convince
convincer noun https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convince#learn-more

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convince#other-words

Answer (score 1):

Ainda podias ter indutor, para além de instigador e persuasor.

O sentido de instigador é mais próximo de instigar **acção** (como resultado da sua influência).

Enquanto o persuasor é mais próximo de provocar **pensamento**.

É preciso ver a razão de o vocabulário ser escaço numa palavra para isto. Penso que é por na tradição a filosofia colocar ênfase na diferença entre **objectivo** e **subjectivo**.

A palavra "***convincer***" é próxima de "***convicção***" que por definição é:

> Certeza de um facto de que **apenas temos** provas morais. [priberam](https://www.dicionario.priberam.org/convic%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Persuadir não implica produzir **provas objectivas**. Persuadir de factos objectivamente verdadeiros -verificáveis ou evidentes- leva a palavras, cuja conotação tem subjacente a verdade objectiva do seu objecto: **explicador, elucidador, esclarecedor** (aqui vemos que até a palavra "professor" é ambivalente quanto à verdade objectiva do que é ensinado).

Não faz grande sentido ter o adjectivo/substantivo "convencedor" por o verbo convencer ser transitivo. Requer um agente e um sujeito, mais não seja na voz reflexiva: convenço-me. É por isso que temos o adjectivo convincente.

**EDIT:** É nestas alturas que me convenço, que a [Filosofia da Lingua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language) Portuguesa tem qualidades extraordinárias. Até porque evidências de verdade objectiva não faltavam aos eruditos que ao longo dos séculos aprimoraram o uso da língua, como a obra de [Tomás de Aquino](http://www.newadvent.org/summa/3.htm) bem prova.